# Multiplying iteration variable in for loop in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, iteration

Would this code increment i by 1 or not?

```
    for i in range(100):
         print(i)
         i*=2
```

Comment: Did you **try it**? What happened?

Comment: move print after multiplication? with the above code snippet your question is not very clear. Also, if you want to change the value of `i` after each iteration to `i=i*2` use `while` loop and not `for ` loop

Comment: At the top of the loop, `i` will take on the values `0`, `1`, ..., `99`.  Within the loop, after executing `i*=2`, `i` will be doubled until the next iteration, after which it will take on the next value in the sequence just as if `i*=2` had never been executed.

Comment: So,how to use update statement in for loop like we use in java?

Comment: You don't. Use a `while` loop instead.

Answer (score 3):

It will increment by `1`. When you use an iterator like `range()`, you assign the next value from the iterator each time, and whatever you assigned to `i` in the loop is ignored.

If you want it to double each time, don't use `range()`, do your own updating and end test.

```
i = 1
while (i < 100):
    print(i)
    i *= 2
```

Answer (score -1):

`i` will start from the first value of the sequence generated by iterator (`range()` in this case) and then it will get multiplied by `2` and it'll retain this value until the next iteration of loop at which it will get the next value of the sequence generated by iterator `range()` so,

```
 for i in range(5):
         print("Before update")
         print(i)
         i*=2
         print("After update")
         print(i)
```

Output:

```
Before Update
0
After Update
0
Before Update
1
After Update
2
Before Update
2
After Update
4
Before Update
3
After Update
6
Before Update
4
After Update
8
Before Update
5
After Update
10
```

Comment: Nowhere OP mentioned to increment the value for `i`. `i` will actually point to a value in the range sequence and nothing to do with increment.

Comment: @mad_ thought the question was asking whether `i` would get updated inside the `loop`. Now I've edited accordingly.